# Can you use regex for fact name in mcollective inventory query?

Tags: puppet, inventory, mcollective

I am attempting to get a list of all IP addresses for each node in mcollective.   The problem I am running into is a wide range of `ipaddress_${interface}` names, especially on newer EL systems who no longer use eth#.   Is there a way to pass a wildcard or regex for the fact name?

My goal is to be able to use `mco inventory` or something equally as quick to produce a report containing every IP address on all nodes:

---

I've attempted and failed at several different reports along the lines of:

`# cat ipaddrs.mc`

```
inventory do
    format "%40s:\t%24s\t%s"

    fields { [ identity, facts["server_role"], facts[/ipaddress_(.*)/] ] }
end
```

`# mco inventory --script ipaddrs.mc`

---

As a work around I am getting a list of all nodes in the collective and grepping the facts I want.  This works but takes several minutes for just a few hundred nodes:

```
for server in $(mco find ); do 
   echo -e "${server}: $(mco inventory ${server}  \
     |grep ipaddress_ |egrep -v '_(lo|flan|dock)' \
     |awk '{print $3}' |sort |tr '\n' ' ')"
done
```